# Recommendations for liveCD retro laptop testing

Tags: laptop, live-cd, sandy-bridge, ivybridge

I'm going to purchase an old laptop soon. (likely a Thinkpad T430 or earlier, maybe a Compaq if I can find one). I'll have the opportunity to test out machines in-person at a re-pc & goodwill outlet.

I'd like to create a livecd (prolly one on usb & one on actual cd) for the purpose of testing out machines in-store - just basic stuff like sound, monitor, keyboard, & battery. What distro & version would you recommend for working with these older laptops? Ideally, I'd like to have something that has basic drivers for a wide array of 2000s-era laptops, specifically with Sandy or Ivy Bridge CPUs.

If anyone's curious, my ultimate goal in buying the machine is to run WinXP on it & use it mostly as a word processor (let the booing commence).

Comment: This is a Ubuntu Q&A site, and the primary difference between them is the age of the software stack on the ISOs; with many releases having kernel stack choice selected by ISO used (so a single ISO will only have a single stack on it; and I'd test using multiple stacks). If it was me I'd put `ventoy` on your thumb-drive & then a number of Ubuntu ISOs (*other choices would be off-topic here*).  I perform QA using modern releases on devices as old as a HP Compaq from 2005 but even release isn't the whole pictured there (ie. GPU on the hardware will also play a part on kernel + toolkits of stack)

Comment: FYI:  I use devices like the *thinkpad sl510* in my QA; it's not the oldest device I have as per last comment; however even that appears to be older than your example *thinkpad t430*. Ubuntu links the kernel stack with a specific ISO with stack selected at download time, thus you're not matching your question with what Ubuntu actually provide (*and Ubuntu is what's on-topic here*).  The ventoy suggestion in prior comment is what I'd likely do, with different stack/ISOs included as choices to be booted.  (*that solution also allows non-Ubuntu ISOs too, though that won't change much*)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @guiverc . I picked ubuntu to ask because that's the distro I have the most familiarity with; wasn't aware that off-topic discussion is so heavily enforced. Is there a better place on StackExchange to ask?

Also I'm not familiar with the term kernel stack, I assume that has to do with bundled drivers available.

Comment: What are commonly called *drivers* are actually linux kernel modules; thus when you change linux kernel, all kernel modules (aka *drivers*) also change. Ubuntu offers kernel stack choice for LTS releases; for older hardware I usually find the older GA stack,  HWE stack for newer; thus for 22.04 ISO and old hardware i'd use an ISO of 22.04 that contains the GA kernel stack (Server uses GA, as do Ubuntu *flavors* of 22.04 & 22.04.1, Ubuntu Desktop & *flavors* of 22.04.2 & higher use HWE).  Ubuntu Desktop ISOs contain more than say Lubuntu ISOs... https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: ie. Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS if using the GA kernel stack will have an install currently using the 5.15 Linux kernel; which in my opinion (*as I'm expressing here*) is generally better for older hardware; in contrast Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (*ie. release details identical!*) when using the HWE kernel stack will be using the 6.5 kernel which is better for newer hardware (esp. graphics/GPU). There are also some OEM options but I'd ignore those (*they exist on Ubuntu Desktop ISOs so I may consider including one of those).  Lubuntu 22.04/22.04.1 media installs GA stack; Lubuntu 22.04.2 & later media uses HWE

Comment: When I wanted a GNU/Linux for an then newish IBM Thinkpad r40p I tried various *distros* to see which performed best... I concluded I liked OpenSuSE as it worked *out of the box* best... In reality it was purely that the kernel used by the OpenSuSE media I'd used better suited the hardware (ie. kernel modules (aka *drivers*) were a better match) than the Debian I'd tried. Newbies will likely say OpenSuSE is better; but I could have tried Debian *testing* (or a newer stack) & achieved what was likely the same result too (ie. age of stack to me is what matters; not which team packaged it).